# Hadoop Map/Reduce with database

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am very new to hadoop , learned about its map/reduce functionality a bit , understands it wordcount demo , but not get the actual use of hadoop map/reduce in relate to database specific computations. That is not getting correct way that how map/reduce help me in some computations or database specific processings. Can anyone provide me a link or some guide which will help me in getting what is the best use and which senerio I can implement to better understand Hadoop map/reduce part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadoop provides with a couple of Input and Outputs formats. The base [InputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html) and the [OutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/OutputFormat.html) classes can be extended for customized Input/Output formats.

DBInputFormat/DBOutputFormat come with Hadoop. [Here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/database-access-with-hadoop/) is the documentation from Cloudera on using the MapReduce with Database.